# How to combine work from more than one developer before checking into TFS?

Tags: tfs

My team's policy is to not check in broken code into TFS. But what if two team members are working on the same file and each member's work represents a partial solution ? One members changes won't work without the other.

How is the best way to combine the code and still follow policy of not checking in broken code ?

Comment: This question raises all sorts of red flags. How are the developers testing their changes locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both developers could create a shelveset of their changes once their own coding is complete. Once it's time to merge their code, you have 1 developer unshelve the other developer's shelveset into their own workspace. Doing this will also trigger the Merge Tool in case there are any merge conflicts that can't be automatically resolved. This should allow the developer to combine work with the other without checking in broken code.

Note that both developers should make a shevleset of their own work before unshelving the other's, in case the unshelve of the other developers work goes terribly wrong in the merge and they need to revert their own work to the un-merged state.

Here's some [documentation on creating and unshelving shelvesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets)

Answer (score 0):

Consider allowing broken code on branches. The team members could commit code to branches and merge those branches together before merging into `master`. Your primary or `master` branch should require a passing build before a pull request can be merged in.

Comment: You're assuming  they're using Git, which is not necessarily the case. The use of TFVC terminology (*checking in*) would indicate they're probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the feature branch model: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/concepts/git-branching-guidance. This does not depend on Git but it is convenient as branching is cheap.

Both developers work on the feature branch which is allowed to be broken. When they are finished they issue a pull request to the master branch. The merge is only allowed if all tests pass to make sure the master branch stays healthy.